linux find in multiple directories limiting by MAX TOTAL SIZE
I have two directories in a 5TB HDD:

folderA
folderB

I  need to rclone sync or rsync these two dirs in another HDD, but the storage is limited to 2TB.
So i decided to sync only the "newest" files and "newest" deletes, removing oldest files on 2TB if there's no space for the newest files.
I need a find command that:

find(with find or ls i guess) all the files in these two dirs, sort by date DESC
limit the output of the command to MAX TOTAL FILE SIZE of 2TB
output the results to a file or pipe to rsync or rclone sync

I have tried this with rclone sync with the command:
MAX_TRANSFER=$(df -Bg /var/HDD| awk '{print $2}' |tail -1|sed 's/%$//g')

/usr/bin/rclone -v --config /home/user/.config/rclone/rclone.conf sync remote:/dir /var/HDD --include='/{folderA,folderB}/**' --order-by 'modtime,descending' --max-transfer $MAX_TRANSFER --check-first --delete-before --size-only --progress --transfers=1

where MAX_TRANSFER is the total SIZE of my HDD
But that doesn't work because rclone just stops itself when reaching 2TB, without syncing newest files and deleting oldest. I need this "mirror" HDD to be always in sync with the newest files created on the 5TB HDD.

I solved it with this shell script.
#!/bin/bash
nc -z 192.168.1.10 22 > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "Host is offline. Skipping sync."
else
        echo "Host is online. Starting sync."

        rm /tmp/syncDir.tmp 2> /dev/null
        rm /tmp/syncDir.txt 2> /dev/null

        MAX_TRANSFER=$(df /home/user/Dir | awk '{print $2}' |tail -1|sed 's/%$//g')
        MAX_TRANSFER=$(($MAX_TRANSFER * 1000))

        /usr/bin/rclone -v --config /home/user/.config/rclone/rclone.conf lsf userpc:/mnt/s/Dir --include='/{folderA,folderA}/**' --order-by 'modtime,descending' --recursive --files-only --format sp --separator "|||" >> /tmp/syncDir.tmp
        total_size=0

        while IFS="" read -r IN || [ -n "$IN" ]
        do
                arrIN=(${IN//|||/ })
                size=${arrIN[0]}
                total_size=$(($total_size + $size))
                if [ $total_size -lt $MAX_TRANSFER ]; then
                        echo -e "$IN" >> /tmp/syncDir.txt
                fi
        done < /tmp/syncDir.tmp

        sed -i 's/^.*|||//' /tmp/syncDir.txt

        /usr/bin/rclone -v --config /home/user/.config/rclone/rclone.conf sync userpc:/mnt/s/Dir /home/user/Dir --files-from=/tmp/syncDir.txt --order-by 'modtime,descending' --check-first --delete-before --size-only --progress --transfers=3
        rm /tmp/syncDir.tmp 2> /dev/null
        rm /tmp/syncDir.txt 2> /dev/null
fi

